# TableView setCellFactory depending on the type of value

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

For example, I have a few classes for the different kinds of cells, depending on the type of the value in the cell (Boolean, date, etc.)

Something like that:

```
public class MyBooleanCell extends TableCell<MyData, Boolean> {...}
public class MyDateCell extends TableCell<MyData, LocalDate> {...}
```

How I can make something like that (pseudocode example)?

```
colValue.setCellFactory(factory -> {
   if (cellValueType != null) {
      if (cellValueType instanceof Boolean) {
         return MyBooleanCell;
      } else if (cellValueType instanceof LocalDate) {
         return MyDateCell;
      } else {
         //...
      } 
   }
});
```

Comment: Why are you not using bidirectional binds?

Comment: And how should the `Node`s you assign to the `graphic` be connected to the items if there are no event handlers/listeners added at all??????? Also how did you design your `FilterRow.filterValueProperty()` to justify this `cellValueFactory` code???

Comment: @fabian add part of `FilterRow` class to post. I must bind my `Node` with property in `setCellFactory`? How I can get property in this part of code to make bind?

Comment: add Some more supporting code, like how your binding the editting text to the model of the table view.

Comment: most probably something wrong in the code you are not showing ;-) Please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @fabian I partly understand what the problem was, thanks for the tip, I reformulated the question more correctly

Comment: Now that code you posted is definetly broken. If I got your question, there can be different data types in the same column. That means however, that the type of item displayed in the cell can change which means you cannot use different `TableCell` classes. This whole setup seems to be non-standard so a few words explaining this would be nice... What I wanted to say was: You may create/display a `Control` in the cell, but that doesn't mean that the value displayed in the `Control` is connected to your `TableView` items in any way automatically...

Comment: @fabian yes, it's pseudocode. Yes, i have a model, which have a ObjectProperty. I want to make table with column with different controls for other datatypes (boolean - checkbox, etc) when edit/display cell. I understand you, i must link my control in cell with model - this problem i solved) I found some examples, which show how i can combine different controls in one cell depending on the value type, but for display only... I don't know how i can combine it for edit purpose...

Answer (score -2):

Try to refresh the TableView by setting the value of the Visibility to false and the true.

tableView --> false
tableView --> true